# Are there nonlinear optimization implementation for OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Are there nonlinear optimization implementation for OpenOffice Calc?

I found one: http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/NLPSolver . But the methods provided there are evolutionary methods, not some more general methods. I would like to find something as close to Excel's solver as possible.

Does LibreOffice Calc has a nonlinear optimization implementation? Is it good to switch to it from OpenOffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Libreoffice-nlpsolver in LO 3.5.7, but in LO 4.0 it comes with the same evolutionary methods as OO.